# Get all methods from a c application

Tags: c

For any c application (let's say apache in this case) I want to return a list of all the methods and the file they are found in. For example, I want would to see something like:

```
int add (int a, int b)..... math.c
int subtract (int a, int b)..... math.c
int Multiply (int a, int b)..... math.c
int foo ()..... foo.c
```

I'd like to do this and avoid the hairy task of manually parsing the physical c files for method output. I know other languages have reflector.

Thanks all.

Comment: For what purpose? Do you want autogenerated documentation?

Comment: No, I am working with a path analysis tool and want to match up some of my output.

Comment: `grep` with regex will go the job..

Comment: Nitpick: "methods" are member functions of OOP classes. C does not have classes which allow member functions, so C program cannot have methods (which is a pity, it could easily have member functions in structs, basically as syntactic sugar, which would make most C programs much more readable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify the platform, so one possible solution is the 'ctags' program:

> DESCRIPTION
>              The ctags utility shall be provided on systems that support the User Portability Utilities option, the Software Development
>   Utilities  option,  and
>              either or both of the C-Language Development Utilities option and FORTRAN Development Utilities option. On other systems, it
>   is optional.
>
> The  ctags  utility  shall  write a tagsfile or an index of objects from C-language or FORTRAN source files specified by the
>   pathname operands. The
>              tagsfile shall list the locators of language-specific objects within the source files.  A locator consists of a name,
>   pathname, and either a search
>              pattern  or  a  line  number  that  can  be  used in searching for the object definition. The objects that shall be
>   recognized are specified in the
>              EXTENDED DESCRIPTION section.
>
> OPTIONS
>   ...
>   -x     Produce a list of object names, the line number, and filename in which each is defined, as well as the text of that line,
>   and write this  to
>                     the standard output. A tagsfile shall not be created when -x is specified.

Answer (score 4):

man nm(1)

But, the symbols source files are only available if the debugging information was compiled in (-g).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/whatis.html). From the site:

> Ctags generates an index (or tag) file of language objects found in source files that allows these items to be quickly and easily located by a text editor or other utility. A tag signifies a language object for which an index entry is available (or, alternatively, the index entry created for that object).

Ctags is [compatible with a wide array of tools](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/tools.html).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for the linker.  Have you tried generating a map file?  Check your linker documentation for how to generate the map file.